# Failed to lookup view "home" in view directory using handlebars

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Hola estoy usando node con express y handlebars pero cuando intento renderizar la vista me aparece el error mencionado.

> Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory
>   "/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/views"    at
>   EventEmitter.render
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
>   at ServerResponse.render
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
>   at index
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/controllers/home.js:15:17)
>   at e
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/controllers/index.js:17:13)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   at next
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   at
>   /home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>   at Function.process_params
>   (/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)

This is my code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
    app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

And the request Handler:

```
index: (req, res,next)=>{
    console.log("entre");
    var markup = react_render.renderToString(index());
    console.log(markup);
    res.render('home', {
        markup: markup,
        state : {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Tienes un fichero llamado `'home.hbs'` en tu carpeta views?

Comment: No, tengo uno llamado home.handlebars.

Answer (score 1):

Estas cambiando la extensión con la que el view engine busca busca los ficheros en la carpeta de las vistas.

Si escribes algo como

```
res.render('home', .....
```

El view engine busca `home.hbs` en la carpeta de las vistas, en tu caso `/views`

```
path.join(__dirname, '/views')
```

Si tienes `home.handlebars` no es el mismo fichero, de ahí el error.

Comment: Cambiando la extension obtengo un error como este:

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/joaquin/workspace/nodejs/EasyRcu/bin/views/layouts/main.hbs'
   at Error (native)

Comment: mi estructura es algo como esto:
->bin
---->www.js
->views
---->layouts
-------->main.hbs
---->home.hbs

Comment: El mismo problema de antes. Le estas especificando unas opciones al view engine `{ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }` y seguramente tienes un fichero llamado `main.handlebars` en la carpeta `/views/layout/` en lugar de `main.hbs`, renombra el fichero al nombre correcto o elimina la opcion para que no use layout.

Comment: @JoaquinNoé Si te fijas en tu layout no coincide con la carpeta `path.join(__dirname, '/views')`, deberías cambiar la carpeta donde apuntas las vistas o cambiar esa opción para que apunte a la estructura correcta de tus ficheros